# Netsuite doesn't trigger user event scripts after Duplicate number screen when saving payment

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

The problem: When I save the customerpayment in UI it triggers the user event scripts before showing the dialog to change the duplicated transaction number (attached). After I change the number, it doesn't trigger the user events.
[image]

How can I catch with my scripts the change of the transaction numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* to be able to manually set (override) the document number for payments?  If not the easiest fix would be to go to Setup > Company > Auto-Generated Numbers, select the Document Numbers tab and uncheck the Allow Override option in the relevant row. Then NetSuite will automatically take care of numbering.

Answer (score 0):

changing the Document number may not be triggering you user event script. Can you try editing and saving the record again. If your user event is designed to work on edit, it will get triggered when you edit and save the record.